# Error when redirect page from Application_Error

Tags: c#, redirect, model-view-controller, session-per-request

I'm trying to do a redirect, I have a singleton class that is my configuration class, picked up the information on this and ride my conectionString, this data I saved in an encrypted file, I am using session-per-request, then before mounting the my need to check for the session configurations file if there is not I throw the exception.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
 {
    if (!Settings.Data.Valid())
       throw new SingletonException();

     var session = SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
     if (!session.Transaction.IsActive)
        session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

     CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
 }
```

If there except I must redirect to the Settings page which is a singleton class.

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
    while (exc != null)
    {
        if (exc.GetType() == typeof(SingletonException))
        {
            Response.Redirect(@"~/Settings/Index");
        }

        exc = exc.InnerException;
    }
}
```

However I am having a problem with this redirection, the link in the browser is changing but I'm having a redirect loop, already tried clearing the cookie and enable the option for external sites.
[image]
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the Application_BeginRequest for dont make nothing when is not valid.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (!Settings.Data.Valid())
                return;

            var session = SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            if (!session.Transaction.IsActive)
                session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using `while` loop so it is infinite loop if  `exc` is not `null`, you have to use `if` condition here:

```
if(exc != null)
{
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(SingletonException))
  {
      Response.Redirect(@"~/Settings/Index");
  }

  exc = exc.InnerException;
}
```

Comment: That while i do for got the firts exception, cause the first error not is my throw. http://imgur.com/aPOT5pg , i remove the redirec just for show u, and i also have tried make it with if.